# NHibernate - mapping collection via non-PK foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Ok, don't ask why, but we have a requirement for the following category structure:

1. A collection of system-defined root categories (we're using an enum for these)
2. A collection of user-defined sub categories, each with a root category id foreign key
3. A collection of system-defined sub-sub-categories

So, it looks a bit like this:

Sys-defined root category -> user-defined sub-category -> sys-defined leaf category -> item

We need to load the pre-defined categories based on the root category of the sub category. For example, if we had:

Vehicles -> My Mondeo -> [Wheels, Stereo, Dashboard]

The user-defined 'My Mondeo' sub-cat would fetch it's child categories based on it's root category (Vehicles).

So we have this kind of reverse many-to-many relationship going on:

```
rootCats --1---------0..*-- user-defined cats
   |                                |
   1                               0..n
   |                                |
   |                                |
   |                                |
  0..*                              |
   |                                |
pre-defined cats--1------------------
```

I have tried to map this in nhibernate with the following:

```
<set name="PreDefinedSubCategories" lazy="false" cascade="none" mutable="false">
  <key column="vaultCategoryId" property-ref="Category" />
  <one-to-many class="PreDefinedVaultCategory" />
</set>
```

However, the property-ref attribute is deprecated and anyhow it throws a 'collection is not associated with any session' error.

Has anyone implemented something like this using nhibernate. If so, is there a nice way of doing it or shall I just define a method to filter through ALL the leaf cats after they have loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot use the where="" attribute of the collection mapping, unless it accepts parameters (I doubt so)

Maybe you should go for :

- a many-to-one from you user-category to your root category
- a collection (one-to-many) from your root category to your sub-sub-category
  This way you can have userCategory.rootCategory.subsubCategories

I guess there is also a relationship table between your user defined categories and your sub-sub-categories (choosen from available sub-sub-categories of root category)
Then go also for a collection(many-to-many) from your user defined categories to your sub-sub-categories